# R Data.Table Rename Many Variables

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame(cat=runif(100), dog = runif(100), fox = runif(100), bunny = runif(100))
```

I just wish to rename such that cat = var01, dog = var04, fox = var07, bunny = var09.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rename` on a named vector and evaluate with (`!!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
nm1 <- c('cat', 'dog', 'fox', 'bunny')
nm2 <- c('var01', 'var04', 'var07', 'var09')
```

Or create it with `seq`

```
nm2 <- sprintf('var%02d',  seq(1, length.out = length(nm1), by = 3))

data <- rename(data, !!! setNames(nm1, nm2))
```

---

Or with `setnames` from `data.table` to change the column names in place by providing a vector of 'old', 'new' names

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
setnames(data, nm1, nm2)

names(data)
#[1] "var01" "var04" "var07" "var09"
```

Comment: let's say it is a case where i have 20 variables. can I just do something like where the new var names are paste("var", seq(01, 09, 03)) ?

Comment: @bvowe You can create that as `paste0("var", seq(1, 60, 3))` (for 20 variables

Comment: @bvowe or use the`length.out` i.e. `nm2 <- paste0("var", seq(1, length.out = 20, by = 3))` `nm1 <- names(data); setnames(data, nm1, nm2)`

Comment: @bvowe if you use `seq` with `by = 3`, it would be `var10` instead of `var09`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rename only specific columns from the data you could use

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  rename(var01 = cat, var04 = dog, var07 = fox, var09 = bunny) %>%
  head

#      var01      var04      var07      var09
#1 0.3817939 0.82917877 0.29435146 0.07547698
#2 0.7235733 0.89619003 0.11643227 0.07026431
#3 0.2500442 0.01800189 0.02804676 0.29175499
#4 0.1229257 0.87631870 0.86204151 0.83269660
#5 0.2191805 0.90387735 0.75390315 0.59554349
#6 0.5019568 0.87161199 0.05806871 0.31988761
```